# MEAN App - Questions on Static Files - restricted API access

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, heroku, digital-ocean

I've developed a MEAN webapp.

So I have an API driven by Node.js and Express. The DB is hosted with mLab. The API is then used by the Angular website, which sits in a static files folder that I have defined in my `server.js` file using:

```
app.use(express.static('site'));
```

(Also FYI: This is hosted with Heroku which I'm looking to move away from in favour of Digital Ocean.)

My question is:

Currently the API is visible across the internet e.g. `xxxxx.com/thesuperapi` however I want only those static files to be able to access it?

Heroku doesn't offer a fixed IP without having to pay for an add-on which i don't want to do. A Digital Ocean droplet would.

Is it possible to control only that folder static can access the API?

Or I guess another way to say it, only the files in the static folder should be accessible to the world.

And is this approach to declare that `.static('site')` the best way to go? Or is there a better practice that I should be following?

Hope that makes sense - any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!